# Changing Bootstrap object`s class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

Im trying to change the object`s class on click. I have a Bootstrap card with button, and I want this button to change the class of this card from "card border-secondary" to "card border-success". Here is the code of this card:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  div class="card border-secondary mb-3" id="neutralsticker" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Task:</div>
    <div class="card-body text-secondary">
      <h5 class="card-title">Short task description</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Detailed task description</p>
      <button type="button" id="goodbtn" class="btn btn-outline-success">Completed</button>
      <button type="button" id="failbutton" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Failed</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a simple code in javascript, found it in familiar questions here, but it doesnt work for me. Maybe you`ll have any suggestions, how to make it work, how to let the button to change the class of object?

```
$(document).ready(function()  {

    $('goodbtn').click(function () {

       $("neutralsticker").removeClass('card border-secondary mb-3').addClass('card border-success mb-3');
       }
    })


})
```

Comment: $("neutralsticker") isn't going to select anything because "neutralsticker" isn't an HTML element.  What you want is to select the ID of "neutralsticker".  So $("#neutralsticker") will actually select it.

Comment: Also, you don't have to remove the class mb-3 and then add it back.  If you removeClass('border-secondary'), it will only remove the class 'border-secondary'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goodbtn` is the `id` value of the button, so you need to access with `id` selector - `#`(`#goodbtn`).

Also you can omit removing `card` and `mb-3` classes, because you again add them in the `addClass`.

```
$('#goodbtn').click(function () { 
   $("#neutralsticker").removeClass('border-secondary').addClass('border-success');
})
```

Example

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {

    $('#goodbtn').click(function () {

       $("#neutralsticker").removeClass('border-secondary').addClass('border-success');
       });

})
```

```css
.border-secondary {
   color: red;
}

.border-success {
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card border-secondary mb-3" id="neutralsticker" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Task:</div>
    <div class="card-body text-secondary">
      <h5 class="card-title">Short task description</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Detailed task description</p>
      <button type="button" id="goodbtn" class="btn btn-outline-success">Completed</button>
      <button type="button" id="failbutton" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Failed</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still not woking, unfortunately.

Comment: @YehorLapko Check the example

Answer (score 0):

Add # with goodbtn. That is why because you are targeting id right now

$(document).ready(function()  {

```
$('#goodbtn').click(function () {

   $("neutralsticker").removeClass('card border-secondary mb-3').addClass('card border-success mb-3');
   }
})
```

})

Comment: $("neutralsticker") should also have an ID or Class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it, but it didn`t help, still no reaction